# How to make up miles to reach a United Airlines elite status?

Tags: loyalty-programs, united-airlines

I have accumulated 93,000 miles by 12/25 this year, 7000 miles short of United 100K status. What are my options to reach 100K status without actually making another flight? Can I buy a trip, but forfeit it, will those miles be accounted toward my elite status?

Purchasing miles directly from United doesn't count toward elite status.

Comment: Why can't you just book a day return flight and fly it?

Answer (score 2):

You don't get miles for buying a ticket, you only get miles for using the ticket to go somewhere.

I am not sure if United has an affinity credit cards that reward you with qualifying miles, but if you don't have one in your hands right now, that option wouldn't be much use for this year.

Likely your only choice is making a mileage run in the next couple of days (and 7000 miles is a bit of a long mileage run ;-).

Comment: There's quite a few [BAEC members considering doing Dublin to Hawaii mileage runs at the moment](http://www.headforpoints.com/2014/12/24/british-airways-hawaii-ex-europe-cheap-ticket/), so in the grand scheme of mileage runs it's not that big ;-)

Comment: There are silly buggers everywhere in the world eh ;-)

Comment: Technically they're silly buggers on the wrong side of the world, once they're half way through the trip ;-)

Comment: UA has some pretty cheap prices to HK right now, at least from YYZ. I think it's for next year though, and whenever it is you have to transit through O'Hare which is worth something to avoid.

Comment: If you can keep up with it, and cope with the signal/noise ratio, the [FlyerTalk Mileage Run Deals forum](http://www.flyertalk.com/forum/mileage-run-deals-372/) is a great source for currently-very-cheap fares on the main (especially US) airlines